# ExtJS: Making an image as a column header

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Is it possible in ExtJS 4.0 to set a column header as a image, or custom rendered HTML?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The API for column text says:

> text : String
>
> The header text to be used as innerHTML (html tags are
>   accepted) to display in the Grid.

Which means you can pass in something like `<span class="mySpan"></span>` and define a css class that has a background image.

*EDIT:*
Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/HSVj8/102/

Comment: I don't think it's gonna work this way. There are gonna be a lot of other stuff around that text which you will not get control over that simple

Comment: sure there maybe some CSS overrides that could get in the way but the general concept works. check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/HSVj8/embedded/result/